# How to extract specific lines from a file in bash?

Tags: shell

I want to extract the string from a line which starts with a specific pattern from a file in shell script.

For example: I want the strings from lines that start with `hello`:

```
hi to_RAm
hello to_Hari
hello to_kumar
bye to_lilly
```

output should be

```
to_Hari
to_kumar
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Did you intend to change the capitalization for "to_Hari"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sed` is the most appropriate tool:

```
sed -n 's/^hello //p'
```

Answer (score 1):

Use grep:

```
  grep ^hello file | awk '{print $2}'
```

`^` is to match lines that starts with "hello". This is assuming you want to print the second word.

If you want to print all words except the first then:

```
 grep ^hello file | awk '{$1=""; print $0}'
```

Comment: No need to use `grep` with `awk` here; specify the regular expression in the `awk` script: `awk '/^hello/ {print $2}' file`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use GNU grep's perl-compatible regexes and use a lookbehind:

```
grep -oP '(?<=hello ).*'
```